# Behaviour of gradient near strict local minimum

Tags: real-analysis

Consider an analytic function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and suppose $0$ is a **strict local minimum**. Is true the following inequality if $\|x\|$ is sufficiently small?

$$
\|\nabla f(x)\|\|x\| \leq \alpha |\nabla f^T(x)x|,\quad \alpha>0
$$

In other words, what I want is a lower bound greater than $0$ for $|\cos\theta|$, where
$$
|\nabla f^T(x)x| = \|\nabla f(x)\|\|x\||\cos\theta| 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1x_2$, so $\nabla f = (x_2, x_1)$.

When $x = (\epsilon, 0)$, $\nabla f(x) = (0, \epsilon)$ and $\nabla f^T(x)x = 0$.

Comment: 0 is not a strict local minimum in this case...